# Get attachments from related object

Tags: soql, attachment

Is there a way to get an attachment from a related object?

Example:

```
SELECT
    RelatedObject__r.Id
  , RelatedObject__r.OtherField
  , (SELECT RelatedObject__r.Id FROM Attachments)
  , ObjFieldOne__c
  , ObjFieldTwo__c
FROM
    CustomObj__c
```

Is this possible? Can't seem to find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

No. In SOQL, you can't go "up then down". The alternative would be to use two subqueries:

```
SELECT OtherField,
       (SELECT ObjFieldOne__c, ObjFieldTwo__c FROM CustomObj__r),
       (SELECT Name FROM Attachments)
FROM RelatedObject__c
```

If this is not feasible for whatever reason, then you would necessarily need to make it two queries.

Comment: Wouldn't the records being extracted be different then?

Comment: If CustomObj had a n-1 relationship to RelatedObject